# Difference between pure-g and pure-g-r

Tags: css, responsive-design, yui-pure-css

I wanted to ask what is the difference between pure-g and pure-g-r .I used to think that the responsive will make my div not collapse in lower resolutions but using pure-g also helped me achieve the same ,so I was confused as to what is the correct difference between them.

[just to mention I was testing using the mozilla's responsive view]

Also adding to this doubt I have seen many blogs mentioning pure classes eg:pure-mobile.. for making your website responsive for mobile,tablets etc . but I couldn't find any description in their own http://pure.css.io site.

Comment: Please don't abuse [html5] and [css3] tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pure-g` class your `pure-u-*` columns won't collapse.

With `pure-g-r`, your `pure-u-*` columns will collapse when viewport is < 768px.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jgvE4/

**UPDATE: if you are reading this today and using PureCSS 0.5+ the answer above is not valid anymore**

Comment: It's not documented because this was before PureCSS became a mobile-first CSS Framework. This answer that is more than 1 year old is valid with PureCSS 0.3.0.